# How to secure AWS Elastic beanstalk domain with using a AWS free tier account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a requirement I have deployed a nodejs app on the Elastic Beanstalk and I am using a free tier instance, the application is deployed successfully but when I opening the domain it is opened with "http", I need to secure the connection with "https".

Can you anyone please help me on this ?
Please note I am using a free tier account.

Regards